# How do i use Count(*) in a where statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dataexplorer

I don't understand why this isn't working and how to fix it, I tried various things like writing

```
select COUNT(p.OwnerUserId)
```

but that doesn't work and I don't understand the error msgs. I don't use MS SQL (I use SQLite and MySQL).

How do i write this query so i can filter the QC by 10 or 50? (where QC > 50 AND ...)

Basically plug in the SQL below into this URL, run it and you'll see 1's in the results.
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

```
SELECT
    TOP 100
    p.OwnerUserId  AS [User Link],
    sum(ViewCount) as VC,
    avg(ViewCount) as AVC,
    COUNT(p.OwnerUserId ) as QC

FROM Posts p
join Users on p.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
where PostTypeId = 1 and ViewCount<10000 and CommunityOwnedDate is null
group by p.OwnerUserId
order by AVC desc
```

Comment: @Matt, This seems like a pure sql question to me.  The content is SO related, but the question is only asking about SQL syntax.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    TOP 100
    p.OwnerUserId  AS [User Link],
    sum(ViewCount) as VC,
    avg(ViewCount) as AVC,
    COUNT(p.OwnerUserId ) as QC
FROM Posts p
join Users on p.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
where PostTypeId = 1 and ViewCount<10000 and CommunityOwnedDate is null
group by p.OwnerUserId
HAVING COUNT(p.OwnerUserId ) between 10 and 50   -- <<<<<
order by AVC desc
```

Another option is to make it a subquery

```
SELECT
    TOP 100
FROM (
SELECT
    p.OwnerUserId  AS [User Link],
    sum(ViewCount) as VC,
    avg(ViewCount) as AVC,
    COUNT(p.OwnerUserId ) as QC
FROM Posts p
join Users on p.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
where PostTypeId = 1 and ViewCount<10000 and CommunityOwnedDate is null
group by p.OwnerUserId
) SQ
WHERE QC >= 50
order by AVC desc
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use Having clause to filter an aggregated field

Try this:

```
SELECT
    TOP 100
    p.OwnerUserId  AS [User Link],
    sum(ViewCount) as VC,
    avg(ViewCount) as AVC,
    COUNT(p.OwnerUserId ) as QC

FROM Posts p
join Users on p.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
where PostTypeId = 1 and ViewCount<10000 and CommunityOwnedDate is null
group by p.OwnerUserId  
HAVING COUNT(p.OwnerUserId ) > 50
order by AVC desc
```

Comment: Think of the WHERE clause as a filter for the FROM, and the HAVING clause as a filter for the GROUP BY (which is where the aggregates are handled).

Answer (score 3):

When you are using aggregates, you should use `having` instead of `where`.

Comment: I never seen (and thus never used) 'having' in my life

Comment: @Acidzombie24: HAVING is a GREAT tool to have. Use it, you will love it!